# Unicode normalization of Hebrew in Tcl, SQLite, or whatever else will work in Linux OS

Tags: sqlite, tcl, hebrew, unicode-normalization

I'm trying to perform joins in SQLite on Hebrew words including vowel points and cantillation marks and it appears that the sources being joined built the components in different orders, such that the final strings/words appear identical on the screen but fail to match when they should. I'm pretty sure all sources are UTF-8.

I don't see a built in method of unicode normalization in SQLite, which would be the easiest solution; but found this link of [Tcl Unicode](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/stringprep/unicode.md) but it looks a bit old using Tcl 8.3 and Unicode 1.0. Is this the most up-to-date method of normalizing unicode in Tcl and is it appropriate for Hebrew?

If Tcl doesn't have a viable method for Hebrew, is there a preferred scripting language for handling Hebrew that could be used to generate normalized strings for joining?  I'm using Manjaro Linux but am a bit of a novice at most of this.

I'm capable enough with JavaScript, browser extensions, and the SQLite C API to pass the data from C to the browser to be normalized and back again to be stored in the database; but I figured there is likely a better method.  I refer to the browser because I assume that they area kept most up to date for obvious reasons.

Thank you for any guidance you may be able to provide.

---

I used the following code in attempt to make the procedure provided by @DonalFellows a SQLite function such that it was close to not bringing the data into Tcl.  I'm not sure how SQLite functions really work in that respect but that is why I tried it. I used the `foreach` loop solely to print some indication that the query was running and progressing because it took about an hour to complete.

However, that's probably pretty good for my ten-year old machine and the fact that it ran on 1) the Hebrew with vowel points, 2) with vowel points and cantillation marks and 3) the Septuagint translation of the Hebrew for all thirty-nine books of the Old Testament, and then two different manuscripts of Koine Greek for all twenty-seven books of the New Testament in that hour.

I still have to run the normalization on the other two sources to know how effective this is overall; however, after running it on this one which is the most involved of the three, I ran the joins again and the number of matches nearly doubled.

```
proc normalize {string {form nfc}} {
    exec uconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -x "::$form;" << $string
}
# Arguments are: dbws function NAME ?SWITCHES? SCRIPT
dbws function normalize -returntype text -deterministic -directonly { normalize }

foreach { b } { 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 } {
  puts "Working on book $b"
  dbws eval { update src_original set uni_norm = normalize(original) where book_no=$b }
  puts "Completed book $b"
}
```

Comment: Blatant self-promotion: I'm working on a tcl library to wrap ICU to improve tcl's unicode support, including normalization. See https://github.com/shawnw/icu4tcl Also a Sqlite extension that does the same: https://github.com/shawnw/useful_sqlite_extensions

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look but likely most of it will be beyond my current skill set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not in a hurry, you can pass the data through [`uconv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uconv). You'll need to be careful when working with non-normalized data though; Tcl's pretty aggressive about format conversion on input and output. (Just… not about normalization; the normalization tables are *huge* and most code doesn't need to do it.)

```
proc normalize {string {form nfc}} {
    exec uconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -x "::$form;" << $string
}
```

The code above only really works on systems where the system encoding is UTF-8… but that's almost everywhere that has `uconv` in the first place.

Useful normalization forms are: `nfc`, `nfd`, `nfkc` and `nfkd`. Pick one and force all your text to be in it (ideally on ingestion into the database… but I've seen so many broken DBs in this regard that I suggest being careful).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm not yet finished running this on all three source but it appears to be working resulting in more matches between sources.  Thanks for the warnings also.  I was just reading a bit of an argument in a [SQLite forum post](https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/d17ad0001cfc78f05a8afb01639102451c55569c86c0a891409e95c97734576a) concerning how Tcl represents data internally and externally and how tclsqlite should work with that.

Comment: Yes. Hebrew is in the Basic Multilingual Plane of Unicode, so it should be just fine in Tcl and SQLite. In terms of internal and external representations, it's best to ignore the Tcl internal one (unless you're writing a Tcl extension) and just pretend that strings are undifferentiated Unicode sequences. External representations are supposed to be standard ones. And as I said, Tcl doesn't include normalizers (so far) as it is a lot of size for a rarely-needed capability.